# get metadata from a result set in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a code in php as:

```
$result = mysql_query($cxn,$sql_query)
$dataset=  mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {
      $dataset[$i]->name
 }
```

I want the above code in zend.

Here mysql_fetch_fields($result) returns the information about fields from the given result set $result.How to do it in zend framework?I have googled it , I found that we can retrieve the information about colums from a particular table but from a result set how to retrieve in zend framework??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible in Zend Framework. Look at [Request solution for result set metadata](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-745). You can try to use experimental [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)

**UPDATE** - example for code in comments

```
sample table structure
table1: id (int), field1 char(3)
table2: id (int), field2 char(3)

<?php

require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');

$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

// create MySQL database adapter
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'test',
    'password' => 'test',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));

// create temporary table
$result = $db->getConnection()->exec('
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTable 
    SELECT
        t1.id,
        t1.field1,
        t2.field2
    FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON t1.id = t2.id
');

// describe
$info = $db->describeTable('myTable');

var_dump($info);

// drop table
$result = $db->getConnection()->exec('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE myTable');
```

[More about running "other" database statements](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.other-statements)

Comment: Thats right.Above method is not working.So what is the alternative for above code written in php?Because I have to get the field name returned from the query.

Comment: You might try using mysql adapter and use Bill Karwin's suggestion http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-745?focusedCommentId=27931&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-27931 `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo   SELECT ...query above...
DESCRIBE foo;`

Comment: Thanks for reply.What should be the syntax if I want to create temporary table as select query from base tables??

Answer (score 0):

I found getting all the metadata about a table to be very simple with Zend Framework.

- first create a DbTable model for your table: [Define Table Class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.defining)
- instantiate the object: `$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_Table();`
- call ->info() on that object : $meta = $table->info()

Here is an excerpt of a dump using this method :[Retrieving Table Metadata](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.info)

```
array(10) {
  ["schema"] => NULL
  ["name"] => string(5) "track"
  ["cols"] => array(6) {
    [0] => string(7) "trackid"
    [1] => string(9) "weekendid"
    [2] => string(7) "shiftid"
    [3] => string(13) "bidlocationid"
    [4] => string(3) "qty"
    [5] => string(4) "lead"
  }
  ["primary"] => array(1) {
    [1] => string(7) "trackid"
  }
  ["metadata"] => array(6) {
    ["trackid"] => array(14) {
      ["SCHEMA_NAME"] => NULL
      ["TABLE_NAME"] => string(5) "track"
      ["COLUMN_NAME"] => string(7) "trackid"
      ["COLUMN_POSITION"] => int(1)
      ["DATA_TYPE"] => string(8) "smallint"
      ["DEFAULT"] => NULL
      ["NULLABLE"] => bool(false)
      ["LENGTH"] => NULL
      ["SCALE"] => NULL
      ["PRECISION"] => NULL
      ["UNSIGNED"] => NULL
      ["PRIMARY"] => bool(true)
      ["PRIMARY_POSITION"] => int(1)
      ["IDENTITY"] => bool(true)
    }
... cont ...
 }
  ["rowClass"] => string(27) "Application_Model_Row_Track"
  ["rowsetClass"] => string(20) "Zend_Db_Table_Rowset"
  ["referenceMap"] => array(3) {
    ["Weekend"] => array(3) {
      ["columns"] => string(9) "weekendid"
      ["refTableClass"] => string(33) "Application_Model_DbTable_Weekend"
      ["refColumns"] => string(9) "weekendid"
    }
    ["Shift"] => array(3) {
      ["columns"] => string(7) "shiftid"
      ["refTableClass"] => string(31) "Application_Model_DbTable_Shift"
      ["refColumns"] => string(7) "shiftid"
    }
    ["BidLocation"] => array(3) {
      ["columns"] => string(13) "bidlocationid"
      ["refTableClass"] => string(37) "Application_Model_DbTable_BidLocation"
      ["refColumns"] => string(13) "bidlocationid"
    }
  }
  ["dependentTables"] => array(1) {
    [0] => string(32) "Application_Model_DbTable_Member"
  }
  ["sequence"] => bool(true)
}
```